# How to join concatenated values from same table in SQL

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

Table entries-

```
ID    Entry       Tags
1      ABC      0001,0002
2      DEF      0002,0003
```

table tags-

```
ID       Tag
0001    Tag1
0002    Tag2
0003    Tag3
```

Is there a way to write a query that returns something like

```
ID   Entry    Tags
1     ABC   Tag1,Tag2
2     DEF   Tag2,Tag3
```

I been searching the web for a while now but without success. I'm not sure what to look for.

Comment: What is the database you are working on? sql-server/oracle/mysql etc

Comment: it is not possible with pure ansi sql, though some database engines provide functions like group_concat to do this, but why do you want to concatenate? maybe it will be easier to do in output logic? and of course it is terrible idea to store all tags in one field, it is better to use separate table

Comment: Your database design violates the first normal form of database design, and it must be changed

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: yep, that's not the design you're looking for.. you need an Entry_Tags(entry_id, tag_id) table to represent the N to N relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the follwoing steps to generate expected output:-

**STEP 1**-- Create Temp Table

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (ID int, entry varchar(50),tags varchar(50))
```

**STEP 2**-- Insert into temp table

```
INSERT INTO #TEMP 
select entries.id,entries.entry,tags.tags
from entries inner join tags
    on ',' + entries.tags + ',' like '%,' + tags.id + ',%'
```

**Step 3** -

```
Select distinct T2.id, T2.entry,
    substring(
        (
            Select ','+T1.tags  AS [text()]
            From dbo.#TEMP T1
            Where T1.id =T2.id
            ORDER BY T1.id
            For XML PATH ('')
        ), 2, 1000) tags
From dbo.#TEMP T2
```

**Suggestion:-** Your database design violates the first normal form of database design, and it must be changed. One column should not contains the ids as comma separated values. There will be severe performance problems and querying will always be difficult.

The first normal form (or 1NF) requires that the values in each column of a table are atomic. By atomic we mean that there are no sets of values within a column.
[Refer Here](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/an-introduction-to-database-normalization/)

Comment: Thanks alot! Specially for suggestion and reference! Guess i've a lot to learn

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're looking for some sort of a cross apply. However it's not really a good idea to have comma separated values within a single column in a table. You'd be better off having an entry table, a tag table and an entry_tag table that would look like

```
Entry_ID  Tag_ID
1         0001
1         0002
2         0002
2         0003
```

And then you join through that table to get the names of the tags. This keeps you from breaking the first normal form and allows you to write queries much cleaner.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have a fundamental flaw in your schema design and, if it's not too late, it should be corrected. You have a many-to-many relationship between Entrys and Tags that should be resolved with a junction table.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you need to fix your relational model, as it is incorrect.

You need 3 entities to represent the relationship many to many, as follows: Entry, Tag, Entry_Tag.

In Oracle database exists a grouping function calls "LISTAGG" to concatenate many results in a single row, so we can group the result of tags for each Entry record.
If you do not use Oracle, need to consult the documentation for your database to find out what is the function that can concatenate the results into a single row.

Finally, a final query should look like:

```
SELECT E.ID, E.NAME, (LISTAGG(T.NAME, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY T.NAME)) Tags
FROM ENTRY E
INNER JOIN ENTRY_TAG ET ON ET.ID_ENTRY = E.ID
INNER JOIN TAG T ON T.ID = ET.ID_TAG
GROUP BY E.ID, E.NAME
```